# Why does the command 'source' have that name?

Tags: shell, command-line, history, shell-builtin, source-command

I wonder why a command that *executes commands from a file in the current shell* is named `source`. I can't see a relation between **run commands in the current shell** and the meaning of the english word **source**. Is there a history behind that name?

Comment: Not english native, but [leo translation to german](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/source) from "to source sth." = "etw. beziehen" is exactly what I understand from what the command does.

Comment: I believe (i.e., always assumed) it is to stand in contrast to invoking a subshell to execute the commands in a file: `sh file.sh` vs. `source file.sh`. Emphasizing that the file is taken as the source of input (stdin) for the current shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Lexico, the Oxford Dictionary site](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/source):

> ### source
>
> VERB
>   [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Obtain from a particular source.

Isn't that exactly what this command is doing? Obtaining variable, alias and function definitions, and other shell settings, from a particular file?

Answer (score 5):

A shell’s purpose is to read commands and execute them, whether that’s interactively or from a script. In that context, I’ve always thought of `source` as specifying the source of the commands the shell should execute (reverting to the current source once it’s finished).

Bill Joy (who introduced `source` in the C shell) defined the command [thus](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/csh-intro.pdf):

> The *source* command causes the shell to read commands from a specified file. It is most useful for reading files such as *.cshrc* after changing them.